# Wrote a function that shortens the strings in an array. Doesn't change the values after the function is finished

Tags: php

I've been searching for an answer on StackOverflow, applying different suggestions but nothing fixed my issue.

I am trying to write a function that takes in an array and shortens each string in the array down to 3 characters. This is the code I wrote:

```
$days_of_week = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");

function stringParse(array $string) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i++) {
        $string = str_replace($string[$i], substr($string[$i],0,3), $string);
        echo $string[$i].'<br />';
    }
    return $string;
}

stringParse($days_of_week);
foreach($days_of_week as $stry) {echo $stry.'<br />';}
```

I've also tried replacing :

```
        $string = str_replace($string[$i], substr($string[$i],0,3), $string);
```

With:

```
        $string[$i] = substr($string[$i],0,3);
```

But that didn't work either.

The output I get is :

```
mon
tue
wed
thu
fri
sat
sun
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
saturday
sunday
```

Which clearly did not change the String values after the function was called. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$days_of_week = stringParse($days_of_week);
```

You need to assign the return value to a variable :-)

This Code works for me:

```
<?php
$days_of_week = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");

function stringParse(array $string) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i++) {
        $string = str_replace($string[$i], substr($string[$i],0,3), $string);
        echo $string[$i].'<br />';
    }
    return $string;
}

$days_of_week = stringParse($days_of_week);
foreach($days_of_week as $stry) {echo $stry.'<br />';}
```

Comment: That's it! I wasn't aware of this. I'll mark your solution as the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$days_of_week = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");

$short_days_of_week = array_map(function($value) { return substr($value, 0, 3); }, $days_of_week);

var_dump($short_days_of_week);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you created returns an array you have to assign it to a variable.

```
$newarray = stringParse($days_of_week);
foreach($newarray as $stry) {echo $stry.'<br />';}
```